# Best algorithm for threshold identitication

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Assume I have huge set of data about a system idle time.

```
Day 1 - 5 mins
Day 2 - 3 mins
Day 3 - 7 mins
...
Day 'n' - 'k' mins
```

We can assume that even though the idletime is random, the pattern repeats.

Using this as a training data, is it possible for me to identify the idle time behavior of the system. With that, can a abnormality be predicted

Which algorithm would best suit for this purpose

I tried to fit in regression, but it can just answer me " What is the expected idle time today "

But what I want to do is. When the idle time goes away from the pattern, it has to be detected.

**Edit:**
Or does it make sense to predict for the current day only. i.e Today the expected idle time is 'x' mins. Tomorrow it may differ

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because higher-level statistics questions belong on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  SO is more for specific programming questions.

Comment: May not be programming. Even without programming, I would need to know which algorithm to apply. Then I can translate it to a working code.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I would try a Fourier Transformation and have a look if your system behaves in a periodic way (this would mean there are some peaks in the frequency domain).
Than get rid of the frequencies with low values and use the rest to predict the system behavior in the future.

If the real behavior differs a lot from the prediction that is what you want to detect.

[wikipedia: Fast Fourier Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)